# Iterating a huge list better alternative approach

Tags: java, android, list, for-loop

I have a text input where users enter a search word, I split this search word into a String Array of words, search the list items' name & description using these search words. Here is my code but it's running really slow on my devices. (I double checked that the slowness is from the `for each` loop not the `RecyclerView`). Can any one suggest my a good example of a better/faster alternative ?

```
ArrayList<CustomItem> original_list = getListFromDatabase();
    ArrayList<CustomItem> filtered_list = new ArrayList<>();

    String input_word = search_word.trim().toLowerCase(); // search_word is assigned by an input field
    String[] parts = input_word.split(" ");

    if (original_list != null) {
        for (CustomItem item : original_list) {
            int number = 0;
            for (String part : parts) {

                if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(part) || item.getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(part)) {
                    ++number;
                }
            }
            if (number == parts.length) filtered.add(item);
        }
    }

    // lastly I assign my filtered list to a RecyclerView

    if (adapter != null) adapter.search(filtered);
```

Comment: The slowness comes from `toLowerCase()` of `item.getName().toLowerCase()` and `item.getDescription().toLowerCase()`. For each iteration, it needs to generate a new String in memory with lower case. Think of some ways to avoid that. One way is to keep a lower case list instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few simple things, such as: you are calling `toLowerCase()` repeatedly for each item. You should do that *once* before that inner loop!

But beyond that, there isn't much left but (potential) usage of multiple threads, to process multiple parts of your data in parallel. But that won't help on small devices with slow CPUs.

Beyond that, other solutions would require to step back: sometimes you have to design your complete data model to support your most performance critical use cases. If the above computations happen very often, it might be useful to store lower cased strings already, to avoid the overhead of doing that later on.

Alternatively, you might have to look into a server side solution, where much of the data resides on a server, and you apply full text search engines on said server to do the heavy lifting.

So, obviously, there are many choices, and what you should do depends on your context, requirements and resources!

Comment: Wow. I never thought this small code could be causing all this. The difference now is really big ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can consider, parallel stream itself and check the difference in performance. Since the functionality that is implemented by you do need any sequence of order for processing..

```
original_list.parallelStream()...
```

after this either filter or do forEach.. as you wish.

Hope this helps. Cheers !!!

Comment: Obviously, that is an "easy" way to enable multithreading. But honestly: in order to be of real value, one has to look at many details. It starts with the processing that takes actually place on the stream. And questions such as: is parallel processing actually possible. And beyond that, `parallelStream()` comes with a lot of overhead, and less powerful Android devices might give you *worse* runtimes when using it ...

Comment: I actually have mentioned that, if there is no requirement of order or sequence, then parallelStream is a good option. I as a matter of fact, mentioned to try it out, and did not mention that this is the perfect solution. :)

Comment: Just saying that "Just try this" isn't a good "answer" most of the time....